# Where can I find a psd edit tool for web

Tags: php, javascript, drupal

I have to put a tool that can edit psd in a drupal website, something like this http://www.buildasign.com/PowerDesign.aspx?T=452B6C497353323269386855786356754F5A376F4A673D3D&cid=1509

Where can I find any sample code?

Mani

Comment: I suggest removing "Drupal" from your search criteria. Drupal may have a mountain of modules to choose from, but if you can't find a Drupal module for what you want, open your criteria to look for Javascript and/or PHP solutions. You can always turn them into a Drupal module yourself.

Answer (score 1):

... the app you referenced is all js so it might be a case for reverse engineering. Aside from that you can look at http://editor.pixastic.com/ As far as I can tell it lacks type editing though.

Comment: It is just for images, reverse engineering might be the last option. Thanks for your answer vector

Comment: ... ehm, well, you know if it was useful in any way ... ;-)